# Handling Dynamic Errors In Go (Specifically database/sql Package)

Tags: string, error-handling, go

Using the `database/sql` package in go for things like `sql.Exec` will return dynamically generated, unreferenced errors such as

```
"Error 1062: Duplicate entry '192' for key 'id'"
```

The problem is that it can also return errors such as

```
"Error 1146: Table 'tbl' doesn't exist"
```

From the same call to `sql.Exec`

How can I tell the difference between these two errors without

1. String comparison, or
2. Pattern matching for error code

Or are those idiomatic viable solutions for this problem?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

database/sql package does not solve this problem. It's driver specific. For example, for mysql you can use:

```
if mysqlError, ok := err.(*mysql.MySQLError); ok {
    if mysqlError.Number == 1146 {
        //handling
    }
}
```

Also, you can find some error constant package, like mysqlerr from VividCortex, and use it:

```
if mysqlError, ok := err.(*mysql.MySQLError); ok {
    if mysqlError.Number == mysqlerr.ER_NO_SUCH_TABLE {
        //handling
    }
}
```

It's not much better than pattern matching, but seems to be more idiomatic.

Comment: Thanks! I should have realized to check the driver. I checked for a solution using type assertion but only read the `sql` package.

Comment: For future users struggling, make sure you import "github.com/go-sql-driver/mysql" also.

Answer (score 0):

I think there's no idiomatic solution, but I wrote a simple function for getting the error number, so you can easily compare them.

In this solution I assume that the construction of the error message is always the same: "Error -some number here-: Error description".

If there's no number in the error or something went wrong it returns 0.

```
func ErrorCode(e error) int {
    err := e.Error() //the description of the error

    if len(err) < 6 { //if its too small return 0
        return 0
    }
    i := 6 //Skip the part "Error "

    for ; len(err) > i && unicode.IsDigit(rune(err[i])); i++ {
    } // Raising i until we reach the end of err or we reach the end of error code

    n, e := strconv.Atoi(string(err[6:i])) //convert it to int
    if e != nil {
        return 0 //something went wrong
    }
    return n //return the error code
}
```

Go playground link: http://play.golang.org/p/xqhVycsuyI

Comment: I think the authors of Go need to address the problems in the `errors` type/package!

Comment: @BlinkyTop What do they need to address? You do realize that the error you get does not come from the `errors.New()` function?

Comment: Well obviously in this case the error type wasn't suitable or descriptive enough for the author of Go's most popular mysql driver. He had to hack out his own version over the error type and now I have to do a type assert on it to even know what it is.